# How to increase slider capture area in Mozilla (input type range)?

Tags: css, mozilla

I want the capture to start outside of the slider. I was able to do this in Chrome but in Mozilla it does not work.

[image]

The way I did it in Chrome:

```
 input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-appearance: none !important;
      height: 14px;
      width: 14px;
      margin-top: 50px; // here I increase
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: -25px;  // here I centered slider
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

And part of code that doesn't work as I need:

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 14px;
      width: 14px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background: red
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like Firefox alternative is [range-thumb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-range-thumb).

Comment: Exactly but it doesn't work as I need. I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox alternative is `::moz-range-thumb` as stated in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-range-thumb#see_also):

[image]

```css
::-moz-range-thumb,
::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="range"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I have styles for mozilla. The problem is it doesn't work as I need. I added my styles.

Comment: I need to have a wider capture area than the area of ​​the slider itself.

Comment: @uiHellen Have you considered using slider library where you can style every aspect of that slider? E.g. https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: unfortunatly no. I use React. :(

Comment: @uiHellen So use react components: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/

Comment: I think I'll have to use this library. Thank you!